# Fetch locale from database instead of browser i18next

Tags: reactjs, locale, i18next

I currently get the locale from the user' browser. The user can now set their preferred language in their profile, this is stored in the database. I would like to get this value from the database and set the right locale for `i18next`. I read something about a own detection functionality here: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector. But I am not fully sure if this is the right thing to use. My i18n.js file is currently setup like this:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { reactI18nextModule } from 'react-i18next';
import moment from 'moment';

export const i18nInit = (callback = () => { }) =>
  // for easy overview use: https://devhints.io/moment its better than official docs:
  moment.defineLocale('nl-custom', {
    parentLocale: 'nl',
    longDateFormat: {
      LT: 'HH:mm',
      LTS: 'HH:mm:ss',
      L: 'D MMM', // need this format to display dates in past year(s)
      LL: 'D MMMM YYYY', // need this format to display dates in the current year
      LLL: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', // need this format as input for the date picker
      LLLL: 'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
    },
  }) &&
  moment.defineLocale('en-custom', {
    parentLocale: 'en',
    longDateFormat: {
      LT: 'HH:mm',
      LTS: 'HH:mm:ss',
      L: 'MMM D',
      LL: 'MMMM D YYYY', // need this format to display dates in the current year
      LLL: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', // need this format as input for the date picker
      LLLL: 'MMMM dddd D YYYY HH:mm',
    },
  }) &&
  i18n
    // load translation using xhr -> see /public/locales
    // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend
    .use(Backend)
    // detect user language
    // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    // pass the i18n instance to the react-i18next components.
    // Alternative use the I18nextProvider: https://react.i18next.com/components/i18nextprovider
    .use(reactI18nextModule)
    // init i18next
    // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
    .init(
      {
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        ns: ['actionpoints', 'common', 'menu', 'messages', 'overview', 'settings', 'shepherdTour', 'users', 'profile', 'meetingtypes'],
        defaultNS: 'common',
        whitelist: ['nl', 'en'],
        backend: {
          // Path where resources get loaded from, or a function
          // returning a path:
          // function(lngs, namespaces) { return customPath; }
          // the returned path will interpolate lng, ns if provided like giving a static path
          loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },

        load: 'currentOnly',
        debug: false,

        interpolation: {
          escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
        },

        // special options for react-i18next
        // learn more: https://react.i18next.com/components/i18next-instance
        react: {
          wait: true,
        },
      },
      callback
    );

export default i18nInit();
```

Is it possible to add a functionality here that fetches the language value from the database and if it is not set it falls back to the locale of the browser?

Comment: I am also interested in whether the locales translations could be fetch in the database. Manually maintain the translations in locales folder is messy

Answer (score 3):

`i18next-browser-languageDetector` detects user's browser language, it may be different then the value stored in DB.

You can make an Api call to the server to get the user lang, if it is not set, use the `i18next-browser-languageDetector` as a fallback.

So the code should look like this

```js
export const i18nInit = async (callback = () => { }) => {
  const {lang} = await axios.get('/user-lang');

  const i18nConfig = i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(reactI18nextModule);

  if(!lang) {
    i18nConfig.use(LanguageDetector);
  }

  i18nConfig.init({
    lng: lang || undefined // if it has value, it will use this lang, if not, it is undefined as a default value of `lng`
    ...
  });
}
```

If you want to go "fancy" you can write a custom async language detector, something like this:

```js
module.exports = exports = function(fallback){
  return {
    type: 'languageDetector',
    async: true,
    init: () => {},
    detect: async function(callback){
      try {
        await axios.get('user-lang')
          .then(language => {
            if(language){
              return callback(language)
            }

            return callback();
          })
      } catch(error){
        callback();
      }

    },
    cacheUserLanguage: function(language){
      // ... cache users lang
    }
  }
};
```

Based on [i18next-react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/0xClpz/i18next-react-native-async-storage/blob/master/index.js#L11-L39a)

Answer (score -1):

I am currently trying to set the languagedetector options to:

```
const options = {
  order: ['localStorage', 'navigator'],

  lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
}
```

So I can make an `axios` call first, then set the value in the `localStorage`. If the value isn't set in the `localStorage` it should look in the `navigator`. If someone has an better answer I will mark yours as the accepted one, I will update this answer later when it works.